# C# DLL noob, how to get functions

Tags: c#

I've been given a dll to talk to a device, I have little to no experience in C# and I'm supposed to get the device initialized by the end of the week. The dll has methods to open ports and send messages, but I have no idea how to get access to the functions

I know its a bit ridiculous to ask but im running out of time.
Thanks,

Comment: What is the language of the program where you integrate the device?

Comment: Can we assume that the DLL is *also* written in C#?

Comment: Did this DLL come with a manual?  Go find one.

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to the .dll file in your C# project.
2. Add a Using namespace at the top of whatever class is going to interact with the .dll methods.

You will now be able to access the methods.

Edit: If your library is unmanaged you'll have to use [Pinvoke](http://www.google.com.bo/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+pinvoke).

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a feature to call from managed code into unmanaged code (which I assume your DLL is) is called [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) and generally involves annotating required `static extern` methods with attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the dll in your project (selet browse to find it) and you should be able to access the functions within. As for how to make your device work with it, I think you're on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is a .Net assembly, you can load it into a Visual Studio project by adding it as a reference.

In the absence of documentation, it can also be extremely helpful to load the assembly into [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), which lets you inspect the guts of the assembly, even to the point of disassembling the code inside the methods.

Answer (score 0):

1- If it is managed Dll , i.e. Written using .net framework than calling a method from the dll is like you are calling a method from your own class.

just add the reference of the dll in your project and include the namespace reference by 'Using' keyword.

2- If it is not than you need to import your dll dynamically, you  can use [DllImport]